# What does happen when we equation two pointer in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

This is a C code to sort the substrings of a large string starting from each index but I cannot understand how can we sort the array a in the code.

As far as I understand:

- we refer `a[i]` to `&c[i]` and thus it created n arrays but doesn't
  `&a[i][1] == &a[i+1][0]`?
- Since `a[i] = &c[i]`, is it true that `&a[i][0] == &c[i]`?
- If not, this looks like a faster way to create n(length of original
  string) arrays, without actually copying it. Is that true?

My code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 1
#define MAXN 5000000
char c[MAXN], *a[MAXN];
int pstrcmp(char **p, char **q){ 
    return strcmp(*p, *q); 
}
int main(){ 
    int i, ch, n = 0, maxi, maxlen = -1;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        a[n] = &c[n];
        c[n++] = ch;
    }
    c[n] = 0;
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(char *), pstrcmp);
    printf("%s",a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "equation" is not a verb – do you mean "assign" or "compare for equality"? Also, "doesn't `&a[i][1] = &a[i+1][0]`?" – no, those are completely different things.

Comment: Use `==` if you want to mean comparison. Use `=` if you want to mean assign.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant it seems to me that `&a[i][1] == &a[i+1][0]`, just before the call to `qsort`, for `i` in range

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `pstrcmp` is a wrapper around `strcmp` that compares two pointers to char pointers. Something like:

```
int pstrcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  return strcmp(*(char**)a, *(char**)b);
}
```

To answer your questions,

- Yes, `&a[i][1] == &a[i+1][0]`. They both point to the `i + 1`-st character of `c`.
- Yes, `&a[i][0] == &c[i]`.
- You are indeed creating pointers to `n` strings, but there is a catch: if you altered any string (say, the last character), you would be altering more strings. So these strings are not independent.

Conceptually, `a[i]` is a pointer to the suffix of `c` starting at position `i`. The program then sorts `a` according to the values of the strings they point to. So, for `c = "abacaba"`, you would get `{ "a", "aba", "abacaba", "acaba", "ba", "bacaba", "caba" }`.

Please note that there are faster ways to build [suffix arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array).

Comment: So, when we are sorting the array a, isn't it changing any character say a[1][1]?

Comment: The characters themselves aren't changing, because nothing in the code overwrites `c` (after the reading part). What's changing is the order of the elements of `a`. So if you were to look at the pointers `a` before and after the sorting, there is still exactly one pointer in `a` pointing to each character in `c`, but their order has changed. So in that sense, yes, `a[1][1]` has changed because `a[1]` has changed.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, I don't see sub-strings, as you don't build any.
Technically, `a` is an array of pointers of type `char` that could make it an array of strings, but the way you link `c` to `a`, effectively `a` is an index of `c`.
Inside the loop, you fill the index char by char. Later when you sort `a`, you sort the index.

The problem with the index is, that you can't really print it out as a string, as it is not a `char *` that the `%s` printf format modifier expects, but a `char **`. This alone should warn you about something spooky. I see that you evaded this problem as hard coding `a[1]` as parameter, but the sole problem of what index to use, tells, that you are going in the wrong way.

I've slightly edited your code, how it would print out the sorted array. If you think it is *not* doing what you want, there is a misunderstanding between what you want and what your code does (except the last `printf`).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXN 5000000
// This is an array of characters:
char c[MAXN];
// This is an array of pointers pointing to individual characters. Essentially, this is an index.
char *a[MAXN];
static int pstrcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2){
    // wrapper between strcmp and qsort's compare signature.
    // See: man 3 qsort -- http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort
   return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
}
int main() {
    int ch;
    size_t n = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        // In this loop, you systematically build up an index, where a[i] points to c[i].
        a[n] = &c[n];
        c[n] = ch;
        n++;
    }
    c[n] = 0;
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(char *), pstrcmp); // Now, you sort the _index_.
    printf("\nc: %s\n", c); // Print Original array.
    printf("a: "); // Print Ordered array:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%c", *a[i]); // Look at the indirection
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. People come, downvote, but doesn't leave a reply why did they downvote :)

Comment: Thanks for the edited code. Can you please tell me why the array c is not changing when we are sorting the array a.

Comment: Because you sort the pointers in `a`, not the values in `c` itself.